# Help with replacing a text with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text in a file called build.xml:

```
component.rollup=true
component.rollup.modules.buildfiles=io-base.xml, io-form.xml, io-xdr.xml
component.rollup_dir=/base
```

I want it to add one file in it so it will become:

```
component.rollup=true
component.rollup.modules.buildfiles=io-base.xml, io-form.xml, io-xdr.xml, io-extended.xml
component.rollup_dir=/base
```

How can I do that with regex?

I'm using javascript.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Forgot to tell you that the files are not static, they may change. Only

```
component.rollup.modules.buildfiles=
```

will always be there.

Comment: You're editing files with javascript?

Comment: @Michael, IE allows this through ActiveX, or it could be server-side JS, e.g. node.js or Rhino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have already read the contents of the file:

```js
fileContents.replace(
  /^(component\.rollup\.modules\.buildfiles\s*=.*)$/m,
  '$1, io-extended.xml');
```

Comment: The only potential problem with this is that if it is run more than once it will keep adding the `io-extended.xml` file to the list. Hence why I made sure in my answer that the line ended in `io-xdr.xml`.

Comment: +1 good answer, but you should include the `=` after `buildfiles` to be safe.

Comment: @GregL: true, I suppose the regex could do a negative lookahead assertion for the "io-extended.xml" filename.  Note that from OP's update I don't think it's safe to assume that any filenames are present though.

Comment: Or you could just do a simple `.match()` check first as I did in my answer. Easier to understand, I find, if a little less technically impressive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming the variable with the XML contents in it is called `myXmlContent`):

```
if (!myXmlContent.match(/^component\.rollup\.modules\.buildfiles=.*io-extended\.xml/im) {
    myXmlContent = myXmlContent.replace(/^(component\.rollup\.modules\.buildfiles=.*)$/im, '$1, io-extended.xml');
```

This will ensure it isn't added twice.